# Visual Studio Extension Selection.Text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating  Visual Studio Extension and I have a problem with Selection.Text.

My code looks like this:

```
  DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
    
            if (dte.ActiveDocument != null)
            {
                var selection = (TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;
                string text = selection.Text;
                selection.Text = text;
            }
```

This code should only to get  and  set same text.
When I call this extension with input text like this :

```
 {
        "$schema": "****",
        "contentVersion": "*******",
        "functions": [
        ],
```

My extension would do this:

```
{
        "$schema": "****",
                "contentVersion": "*******",
                        "functions": [
                                ],}
```

Why is this happening? Why each line is moved to right by one tab?

**Does anyone know how to get  and set some text without selection in Visual Studio extension?**

**Does anyone know how to set folds in Visual Studio extension?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio automatically formats code when using `selection.Text = text;`

You can use `selection.Insert(text);` instead to set text as is.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to create new outlining? Which part of code provides me that?

Comment: @SrnaNikolic Please create a separate question about outlining as it is separate from selection.